# Am getting empty strings in my django database when trying to save JSON data from ajax request

Tags: jquery, json, django, ajax, database

Am new in coding skills so am creating a website now am stuck , in my website users answer a question by clicking one button choice out of many button choices , i want when a button is clicked data to be sent to the django database but unfortunately when i click the button only empty strings is sent to the database

views.py

```
import json

from django.http import JsonResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.urls import reverse
from .models import JasonData
from .form import QuestionForm
# Create your views here.


def index(request):
    """The homepage for Stay_healthy"""
    return render(request, 'Stay_healthy/index.html')


def redirect_to_index(request):
    """The homepage for Stay_healthy"""
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index', args=None))


def json_data_store(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # this runs incase the request is an ajax
        if request.headers.get('HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH') == 'XMLHttpRequest':
            data = json.loads(request.body)

            form = QuestionForm(data)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                return JsonResponse({'status': 'success'})
            else:
                return JsonResponse({'status': 'error'})
        else:  # this runs incase the request is not ajax
            form = QuestionForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                return redirect('index')

    else:
        form = QuestionForm()

    return render(request, 'Stay_healthy/question_detail.html', {'form': form})


def check_data(request):
    stored_data = JasonData.objects.all()

    return render(request, 'Stay_healthy/check_data.html', {'stored_data': stored_data})
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.


class JasonData(models.Model):
    patient_data = models.JSONField(blank=True, null=True, default=dict)
```

form.py

```
from django import forms

from .models import JasonData


class QuestionForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = JasonData
        fields = ['patient_data']
```

html doc

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% extends "Stay_healthy/base.html"%}
{% load static %}
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>age</title>

</head>
<body>


{% block content %}
<h1>Welcome let's find how care at Forward can meet your unique needs. What is your age?</h1>
<h2 class="highlight">looks like you are thriving motherfucker </h2>
<form action="{% url 'Stay_healthy:json_data_store' %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
  <div class="criteria">
    <button id="age1" type="button">18-29</button>
    <p></p>
    <button id="age2" type="button">30-39</button>
    <p></p>
    <button id="age3" type="button">40-49</button>
    <p></p>
    <button id="age4" type="button">50-59</button>
  </div>
</form>

<script src="{% static 'js/question_detail.js' %}"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/question_detail.css' %}">

{% endblock content %}
</body>
</html>
```

javascript file

```
// retrieving the CSRF token from the cookie
function getCookie(name) {
  var cookieValue = null;
  if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
    var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
      var cookie = cookies[i].trim();
      if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
        cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  return cookieValue;
}
//storing data using ajax
document.getElementById("age1").addEventListener("click", function () {
  var patient_choice = "18-28";

  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("POST", "/store-choice/", true);
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/application/json;charset UTF-8");

  // Include the CSRF token in the request
  var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');
  xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);

  var jsonData = {"choice": patient_choice};
  xhr.send(JSON.stringify(jsonData));

  // redirect to another page
  window.location.href = "/index"


});
```

url.py

```
"""defines urls for stay_healthy."""

from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'Stay_healthy'
urlpatterns = [
    # homepage
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    # page for criteria for being a candidate
    path('question_detail/', views.json_data_store, name='question_detail'),
    # path for storing data of patients
    path('store-choice/', views.json_data_store, name='json_data_store'),

    # viewing stored data
    path('check_data/', views.check_data, name='check_data')
]
```

Comment: First thing that you can see is that you have an error `application/application/json` it should be `application/json`.

Comment: Typo: `"choice"` → `"patient_data"` in `var jsonData = {"choice": patient_choice};`, i.e. `var jsonData = {"patient_data": patient_choice};`